# Is there any way to get an option tag value and pass it to a helper in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am working with express and handlebars, so I have a view where I want to show some information given the event when the client select an option from a *select* tag, and firstly, I have some questions about it:

1. Is it possible to take an option tag value and send it into a helper?
2. Is there any way to call a helper when the onChange event is triggered?

I have tried to make the helper accessible from a script included in the view's html but then I realize is the same as having it declared on app.
Also tried to get the tag value with a javascript and return it to the html, but that did not work neither.

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div>
      <label for="zoneSelect"><span class="control-label badge badge-light">Zone monitoring</span></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="zoneSelect" class="custom-select" onchange="{{eventHandler selectedOptionValue }}">
        {{getZones zones}}
      </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

```
getZonas: function(zonas) {
    var str;

    zonas.forEach(element => {
      str += '<option value="'+element._id+'">' + element.nombre + '</option>';
    });
   return new Handlebars.SafeString(str);
}
```

So, my idea is to send the selected option from the select and send it to a helper that works with that information as shown in the code.

The helper above is to build the options tag to the select dropdown and zones is json data retrieved from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you messed up a frontend and backend. Event handling happens on a frontend. The handling code should be part of your view but not the backend.

```html
<script>
  function onZoneSelect (value) {
      // Real action here
      console.log('ZONE', value);
  }
</script>

<select id="zoneSelect" class="custom-select" onchange="onZoneSelect(this.value)">
  <!-- This code could be generated on backend with handlebars -->
  <!-- BEGIN -->
  <option value="Z01">Zone 01</option>
  <option value="Z02">Zone 02</option>
  <option value="Z03">Zone 03</option>
  <option value="Z04">Zone 04</option>
  <option value="Z05">Zone 05</option>
  <!-- END -->
</select>
```